# Wanting to add a simple calendar widget on my sharepoint homepage

Tags: calendar

Exactly as the title states, how do I add a calendar widget to my sharepoint site? I've been googling but all I get are addons and downloadble things and code and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

Add a View of a Calendar list on the page.

For 2010:

1. First create the list like this video shows you: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vzy_9yyKDTQ (before that you might need to activate the Group Work Lists feature, like this http://sensoft2000-sharepoint.blogspot.se/2011/07/issue-calendar-list-is-missing-in.html)
2. Then add a webpart to your page like this http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/add-a-web-part-to-your-page-in-sharepoint-2010.html, selecting Lists and Libraries and then your Calendar list.
3. Then click the arrow in the upper right of the webpart while the page is still in Edit mode. Click Edit Webpart.
4. Under List Views in the Toolparts you see "Selected View", select "Calendar" if you do not already see the calendar.
5. Save the page

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a 'widget' out of the box. You can add a calendar view but it takes over the entire thing. Check out http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2013/04/small-calendar-for-sharepoint-2010-2013.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+SharepointBrandingDesign+%28SharePoint+Branding+%26+Design%29 for some quick CSS for taking a normal calendar and making it much smaller, like your widget.